# Swagger, API Blueprint, RAML... How Do You Keep Your API Spec and Implementation In Sync?

Tags: swagger, apiblueprint, raml

I am quite new to the world of Web API description languages and have just started researching Swagger, API Blueprint and RAML for our JAX-RS applications.
They all look great but I have one question.

My understanding is in the top-down approach, you design you API first, generate a nice HTML documentation, possibly as well as a mock, then start coding.

But what if you end up having to change the signature of your API, eg, changing the response body model, for some reasons during implementation?
I mean in that case your API spec needs to be changed and you have to edit your API Spec manually in order to keep it in sync with your code since there seems to be no mature library that generates API Spec from source code.
(I have tested such libraries for Swagger and RAML but not APIB, since I couldn't find a JAX-RS source-APIB conversion library.)
In such case as above, how do you deal with it?

Do you edit API Spec manually or use some library to do it automatically?
If the latter, could you please let me know the name of the library?

Comment: FWIW, swagger-core is being developed for ~4 years, not sure why you find not not mature.

Comment: With the top-down approach, you can also generate programmatic artifacts (like JAX-RS annotated interfaces and DTOs) that keep your code in sync with your specs at compile time. So the spec drives dev at all time, there's no code initiated changes that would inadvertently break the contract.

Comment: @Ron, thanks for the response and "mature" may not be the right word. As for Swagger, we are not allowed to use Swagger runtime annotations and the only source-to-Swagger library I found on this site was not able to reproduce the whole thing of our Web API in Swagger format.

Comment: You mean the swagger-maven-plugin?

Comment: @David, thanks for the comment. I'm aware of the impressive tools for RAML (especially API Designer and API Console!) My concern might sound silly but in the past we have experienced having to change the API signature (request parameters) when we were close to the final E2E test, due to customer demands. I suppose if things like that happen again with the top-down approach, we would edit the API Spec manually but would not probably generate source from it, because copying and pasting the existing code into the newly generated skeleton doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: @Ron, no, the tool I tried was swagger-jaxrs-doclet by teamcarma. I wasn't aware of the Maven plugin you mentioned. I will try it tomorrow! Thanks! Now, I'm really hoping swagger-ui will be updated soon to include the fix for proper rendering of response headers...

Comment: @tsz662 To the opposite: you would actually regenerate artifacts after changing the RAML. These artifacts are interfaces and DTOs so none of the existing code would be wiped out but it would stop compiling and would prompt you into fixing it. So no copy/pasting but instead compiler-driven fixes to make sure the code does what the RAML spec says it should do...

Answer (score 3):

The best thing I know from this perspective is [JSight](https://jsight.io). It directly addresses the "API documentation accuracy" problem.

Let me explain the main idea.

There are two ways of creating API docs:

1. **Spec first approach**. First, describe API using some API definition language (e.g. [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/)); second, code the service; third, maintain API docs, constantly syncing it with the implementation.
2. **Code first approach**. First, create the service; second, generate docs from the service code, using the docs generator; third, constantly regenerate the docs after each service API change.

The first approach (Spec first) is more natural. It is always more natural firstly to think, then to make. Most API experts advise creating API specs first. But this approach has **two huge flaws**:

1. Commonly used API description languages are not human-friendly (OpenAPI, RAML, API Blueprint, etc.). Writing or amending API specs using these languages is a big pain.
2. It is hard to sync API docs and physical API implementation.

That is why 40% of developers still stick to the second Code first approach!

**JSight was created to solve the two main problems of the Spec First approach mentioned above**. This is how it solves them:

1. JSight is an amazingly [user-friendly language](https://jsight.io/docs/jsight-api-0-3-quick-tutorial/lesson01) (see example below).
2. JSight has a cross-platform high-performance [message validator](https://jsight.io/products/jsight-validator/), which checks each request/response against the API spec.

How does it change the situation?

1. With JSight API language it is easy to design API first. It is not a pain anymore.
2. JSight Message Validator constantly checks that the API spec is synced with the API implementation.
3. When a developer makes amendments to the service code, he is forced to make corresponding amendments in API spec (because of the Message Validator). But it is not a pain anymore, not a pain.

Thus, JSight solves your problem and improves the natural Spec First approach.

Example of JSight API spec:

```
JSIGHT 0.3

GET /user/{id}
  200
    {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "John"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assure your API description and documentation in sync, make sure you have a look at [Dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd/).

Dredd's tagline is:

> No more outdated API Documentation

Dredd is an API testing framework which consumes API Blueprint and tests it against API backend. You can very easily make it part of your test suite so it can be part of whole developement lifecycle. From design through local TDD, continuous integration and even post deployment verification of live APIs.

So I recommend to edit/compose API description manually as a part of design process and then test it instead of generating documentation from code.

*Disclaimer: I'm a Dredd maintainer*

Comment: thanks for the comment. I am aware of Dredd and will soon try it at work (I'm currently writing sample API using Atom API Blueprint plugin). I'm sure Dredd will play a significant role in the situation I commented above. BTW, why no one writes source-to-API Blueprint library? (I know Restlet Studio is planning to implement such feature, though.)

Answer (score 0):

For RAML, you can have a look at [abao](https://github.com/cybertk/abao). It is a command line utility to check if the RAML-specification matches with the backend implementation. I have not used it myself, but it seems equivalent to Dredd.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it looks like we're going to adapt swagger. If anything comes up with swagger's tool chain, we may change our course and in that case, I'll definitely check abao out.